# Basic parsing structure for nested structures?

Tags: parsing, antlr, grammar

I've come across the following bnf quite frequently for parsing a basic arithmetic expression:

```
S :== EXPRESSION
EXPRESSION :== TERM | TERM { [+,-] TERM] }
TERM :== FACTOR | FACTOR { [*,/] FACTOR] }
FACTOR :== number | '(' EXPRESSION ')'

-- or --

expression :    term | term + term | term − term
term :      factor | factor * factor | factor / factor
factor :    number | ( expression ) | + factor | − factor
```

This would parse something like `2+3-4*(1+2)`. However, what is required to parse something like `1+1+1+1`, as the above factor cannot also refer to the expression production itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first version is correct, but not BNF. It uses "extended" syntax, which includes the repetition operator `{ ... }`, which means "zero or more instances of the pattern inside the braces". So `TERM { [+,-] TERM] }` means `TERM` or `TERM + TERM` or `TERM - TERM + TERM` or `TERM + TERM + TERM - TERM`, etc.

Your second version is not correct (and does not correspond to the first version). You don't provide any citation for it, so I can't tell if you copied it incorrectly or your source was simply wrong. Here's a correct version:

```
expression: term | expression + term | expression − term
term:       factor | term * factor | term / factor
factor:     number | ( expression ) | + factor | − factor
```

I hope it becomes clear how that analyses `1 + 1 + 1 + 1` into a left-associated sequence of additions.